# Tracing web shell attack with Linux audit system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, audit-logging

I tried to trace web shell attack using Linux audit system.
Following is the rule I appended.

`-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F gid=nginx -S execve`

(using nginx)

With this setting, I can trace commands not 'pwd', but 'ls', 'cat'.

What are differences those had? And how can I trace all commands thoroughly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Things like `pwd` are shell built-ins and do not involve the creation of another process, and thus no call to `execve`. The built-in commands supported depend on the shell you're using. Here are the [built-ins supported by bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html).

I would recommend that you either run a modified version of the shell or that you trace something else, such as network traffic, if you really wish to capture all activity. Without more details on why you wish to capture this information, it is difficult to recommend an approach.

Comment: You realize that my answer will be moved if the question is moved, right? You realize that I voted to have this question moved? No reason to downvote for that.

Comment: I know your answer will move but no, I didn't know you voted to move. How would I know since you made no mention of it being in the wrong place?

Comment: Add a sentence educating the OP and I'll retract the downvote

Comment: So that useless sentence can move with the answer?

Comment: So add a comment and tell the user yourself. Otherwise, if the community doesn't move it, perhaps it doesn't need to be moved.